# pip install with relative paths in poetry

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

How do I specify relative paths that *pip* can use in *poetry*'s `pyproject.toml`?

*poetry* successfully installs them, however pip fails with the following error:

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ck09aiax/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/poetry/core/packages/directory_dependency.py", line 36, in __init__
        raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
    ValueError: Directory ../lib_foo does not exist
```

---

*Example*

I have the following repository structure

```
.
├── lib_foo
│   ├── lib_foo
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── pyproject.toml
└── main_app
    ├── main_app
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── pyproject.toml
```

`main_app` is dependent upon `lib_foo`, its dependecies looks like this:

`./main_app/pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7"
lib-foo = { path = "../lib_foo" }  # also tried  path = "../lib_foo/"
```

when doing:

```
./main_app$ poetry install  # runs successfully 
./main_app$ python -m pip install ../lib_foo/  # runs successfully
./main_app$ python -m pip install .  # fails with the error mentioned above 
./main_app$ python -m pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from ./main_app/my_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

---

I am using `poetry` when developing a project however when deploying them I want to only use `pip`

---

A related [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127)

Comment: As far as I remember, this is not supported. The issue is that writing paths in Python distributions (_sdist_ or _wheel_) is somewhat shaky, and even more so when it is relative paths. I will try to find some concrete evidence of that, I think I saw it not too long ago.

Comment: @sinoroc there seems to a [PR](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/9091) that might fix this?

Comment: I do not think it is related, I might be wrong.

Comment: I see you already asked the question and got answers here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127 -- So why haven't you added this link to the question?

Comment: @sinoroc will edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure *pip* can not handle dependencies with relative paths. Absolute paths might be okay.

The way I see it, *pip* gets dependencies in the [core metadata format](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-dist-multiple-use), so for dependencies the format is [*PEP 508*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#abstract), which says:

> the URL reference form, specified in PEP-440 [4] is not actually implemented in pip, but since PEP-440 is accepted, we use that format rather than pip's current native format.

And [*PEP 440*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#file-urls) says (emphasis mine):

> File URLs take the form of `file://<host>/<path>`. If the `<host>` is omitted it is assumed to be `localhost` and even if the `<host>` is omitted ***the third slash MUST still exist***.

Which I naively interpret as all paths must be absolute.

---

***Related***:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127
- https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3148

Comment: pip does handle dependencies with relative paths, It seems it has a bit of an [inconsistency](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127#issuecomment-726186025)

Comment: Looks like they agree with me: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9127#issuecomment-726215622

Comment: seem to be, I guess this might be a bit of antipattern?

Comment: I don't know... There are things that are somehow possible, but people should not do, and they do it anyway, then complain when it does not work. -- It's fine that _poetry_ allows this in `pyproject.toml` for their own purposes, but it should not allow it to be written in the distribution metadata, because it simply is not allowed. -- I think it was already discussed in a poetry ticket. -- As far as I know, _PyPI_ would plainly reject such distributions (with path dependencies relative and absolute) from being uploaded.